# Order by count of relational field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following relations:

`Member` one-to-many `Product`

`Product` many-to-one `Member`

This is the query that I have that works:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
$qb
    ->where('m.Authority = :Authority')
    ->setParameter('Authority', Authority::CREATOR)
    ->innerJoin('m.Product', 'p')
    ->select('COUNT(p) AS HIDDEN item_count', 'm')
    ->groupBy('m')
    ->orderBy("item_count", "ASC");
```

However when I add additional parameters for product status

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
$qb
    ->where('m.Authority = :Authority')
    ->setParameter('Authority', Authority::CREATOR)
    ->andWhere('p.Status = :Status')
    ->setParameter('Status', 1);
    ->innerJoin('m.Product', 'p')
    ->select('COUNT(p) AS HIDDEN item_count', 'm', 'p')
    ->groupBy('p')
    ->orderBy("item_count", "ASC");
```

The order by doesn't happen anymore. I dumped the value for `item_count` and it's alway `1`. Has anyone encountered the same problem? The goal here is to get a list of Members with Products with status = 1 ordered by the number of Products.

Edit:
If I change `groupBy('p')` to `groupBy('m')`, it will only load one related `Product` for each `Member`

Comment: well ... if you group by product, obviously the product count is always 1, and the ordering works fine, because there is no higher count coming before other counts. also, if you group by m, all rows of one member are collapsed, hence you only get one product p, but should get the correct count of products. I have this feeling, you don't exactly understand how group by works. to cut this short: with only one join (and no subquery) you will **not** be able to get both all the single products AND the product count as an aggregate. you either need to add another query or another join /subquery.

Comment: Thank you @Jakumi. Your comment helped me get in the right direction. I've given an answer to my own question. Although I've got it working there is still something that puzzles me. Maybe you can help me figure it out some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who struggled with the same problem, this is how I did it:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
$qb
    ->where('m.Authority = :Authority')
    ->setParameter('Authority', Authority::CREATOR)
    ->andWhere('p.Status = :Status')
    ->setParameter('Status', 1);
    ->select('p, m')
    ->addSelect('(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p1)
    FROM Eccube\Entity\Member m1
    INNER JOIN Eccube\Entity\Product p1
    WHERE m1.Authority = ' . Authority::CREATOR . ' AND p1.Status = 1 AND p1.Creator = m.id
    ) AS hidden item_count')
    ->innerJoin('m.Product', 'p')
    ->groupBy('p')
    ->orderBy("item_count", "ASC");
```

It works but I don't understand why this is `p1.Creator = m.id` ? If I use `m1.id` it will just sum up the item count.

Edit: Added updated code after Jakumi's comment regarding the join. Even though both code works, the second one makes more sense.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
$qb
    ->where('m.Authority = :Authority')
    ->setParameter('Authority', Authority::CREATOR)
    ->andWhere('p.Status = :Status')
    ->setParameter('Status', 1);
    ->select('p, m')
    ->addSelect('(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p1)
    FROM Eccube\Entity\Member m1
    INNER JOIN m1.Product p1
    WHERE m1.Authority = ' . Authority::CREATOR . ' AND p1.Status = 1 AND p1.Creator = m
    ) AS hidden item_count')
    ->innerJoin('m.Product', 'p')
    ->groupBy('p')
    ->orderBy("item_count", "ASC");
```

Comment: the thing is, that this subquery-select *without* m1 instead of m has NO correlation to the *main* query., it'll then count all products for all members. your join is a bit weird, you might have tried `inner join m1.Product p1`. you might get away with not having m1 at all and just say `p1.creator = m` tbh. but I'm not entirely sure, how much doctrine orm knows about the entities and how much magic is going on ;o)